Protagonist fakes death to protect himself and family
I'm searching for  movie I watched maybe 10 years ago. 
I don't remember its name, but in the end, a car explodes and the main character is believed to be dead, but it's just to throw off those who tries to kill him and his family. I think it involves some kind of training phase where he learns to be someone else, but I'm not sure. In general there is a lot of twists. Genre: Thriller, from US

Do you remember anything else? Anything else at all? Because your description sounds pretty vague as it is.

Well, I remember that the car exploding at the end is in front of his home, and that we (the viewers) believes that he has died. Later we understand that he has done this to get away from the "bad guys". The main character also kills during the movie, but I don't remember if he is an assassin or not. It is probably from the 1990's and I thought it was The Jackal, but it doesn't have that scene does it?

Do you remember any lines/quotes from the film? Where abouts it was set? A description of the main character? A description of the bad guys?

No lines, sorry. And the bad guys is probably an organisation. I'm truly sorry for the poor information, but I watched it ages ago, and it just hit a week ago me how good I thought it was back then. Its probably a B-movie, because I have looked around without any luck.
Thank you for helping :)

It could be The Assignment (1997) with Aidan Quinn.
Protagonist Annibal Ramirez (played by Quinn) is trained to masquerade the terrorist Carlos the Jackal.
At the end of the movie CIA fakes the deaths of Ramirez and his family in car explosion, so they may live safely with a new identity. 

Thank you so much!! The Assignment was the one I was thinking about. Been bugging me for a long time. Amazing work, thank you !

Could it be Eraser with Arnold Schwarzenegger?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116213/
Arnold plays a guy who "erases" people who are in a witness protection program and who's lives are in danger.  At the beginning of the movie,  he saves an informants life by changing his identity with that of a dead man, destroying this guys home/safe house with the dead guys corpse in there to make it look like the informant died.
At the end (without giving much away) Arnold's car blows up in front of a courthouse with all the people who wanted him dead watching.  Everyone thinks he is dead, but he isn't.
